# Revert GRUB config changes from installing desktop-base

Tags: debian, gnome, grub2

I've got a Debian 10 box which has no desktop environment currently installed. I'd like to put vanilla GNOME on it, but I've noticed that when I install the `gnome` package via apt, the `desktop-base` package changes the theme of the GRUB screen on boot.

Without desktop-base installed, the GRUB screen is blue and plain, and with it installed, it is gray with the Debian logo everywhere. Does anyone know how to revert this once `desktop-base` is installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`, which reads `/usr/share/desktop-base/grub_background.sh` if `desktop-base` is installed:

```
if [ -f "/usr/share/desktop-base/grub_background.sh" ]; then
        . "/usr/share/desktop-base/grub_background.sh"
fi
```

If you delete those three lines from `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`, and run `update-grub` (as root), you’ll get the plain blue screen back.